# Limitar los permisos nuevamente de una carpeta

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Tengo mi PHP en la siguiente ruta: OPT/LAMPP/HTDOCS/PAGINA WEB... Para que el lenguaje me permitiera crear documentos con una función llamada FOPEN tuve que dalre permisos totoales a la carpeta LAMPP, con el siguiente código:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 lampp
```

Todo salio bien, pude crear los documentos desde php con fopen. Pero hoy, que quiero practicar con base de datos, y entro al phpmyadmin, me aparece el siguiente mensaje: **Permisos incorrectos en el archivo de configuración ¡cualquiera no debería poder modificarlo!**... Supongo que tengo que la solución es quitarle los permisos totales nuevamente a mi carpeta lampp, **pero no sé invertir los comandos**.

Comment: El comando para cambiar los permisos ya lo has usado, solo averigua que permisos necesitas, consulta este artículo que te puede ayudar: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Answer (score 1):

Lo importante es que el usuario que utiliza tu servidor ( el cual ejecuta el interprete de php ) tenga los permisos para acceder a dichos archivos. ahora si usas apache2 por lo general dicho usuarios es `www-data` por lo que primer lo que hay que hacer es cambiar el grupo de los archivos.

```
sudo chown -R :www-data  OPT/LAMPP/HTDOCS/PAGINA
```

aquí lo que estamos haciendo es que los archivos de la pagina pertenezcan al grupo `www-data`. ahora como te dice el php myadmin con permisos 777 le estas diciendo a la computadora que dichos archivos pueden ser leídos, escritos y ejecutados por cualquiera ( desastre total ) por lo que debes cambiar a un formato de permisos donde solo el dueño de los archivos o miembros del mismo grupo puedan editarlos. para esto hacemos

```
sudo chmod -R 774  OPT/LAMPP/HTDOCS/PAGINA
```

Allí le estamos dando permisos totales tanto al dueño del archivo (el primer 7), al grupo de los archivos (en este casos `www-data`, con el segundo 7) y el 4 indica que el resto de los usuarios solo tienen permiso de lectura. Aquí ya debería funcionar bien tu aplicación. pero en algunos casos el grupo tampoco debería tener todos los privilegios.

Para aclarar lo de los permisos te recomiendo leer esta [documento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permisos_de_acceso_a_archivos) de wikipedia

> Notación octal
>
> Otra forma muy común de representar los permisos Unix es la notación
>   octal, que consiste en un valor de tres o cuatro dígitos en base 8.
>
> Con la notación octal de tres dígitos, cada número representa un
>   componente distinto del conjunto de permisos: clase de usuario, clase
>   de grupo y clase del resto respectivamente.
>
> Cada uno de estos dígitos es la suma de los bits que lo componen
>   (véase también sistema de numeración binario). El peso de cada bit en
>   un dígito es el siguiente:
>
> ```
> El bit de lectura suma 4 al total.
> El bit de escritura suma 2 al total.
> El bit de ejecución suma 1 al total.
> ```
>
> Estos valores nunca producen una combinación ambigua: cada suma
>   representa un conjunto específico de permisos.
>
> He aquí los ejemplos de la sección Notación simbólica de más arriba en
>   su notación octal:
>
> ```
> "-rwxr-xr-x" se representa como 755 en notación octal de tres dígitos.
> "-rw-rw-r--" se representa como 664 en notación octal de tres dígitos.
> "-r-x------" se representa como 500 en notación octal de tres dígitos.
> ```

Comment: Le tuve que dar permisos totales porque php me tiraba error cuando intentaba crear un documento vacio con su funcion FOPEN. Me decia que no tenia permisos suficientes, por eso se los di. SObre lo otro ¿le puedo poner el nombre que quiera al grupo, y no www-data?

Comment: Si puedes cambiar el nombre, pero no te lo recomiendo. porque es un estándar y a la final es mas cómodo cuando tienes que realizar otro trabajo. y si haces lo que te comento no te debería dar problemas. debido a que el php tendra los privilegios del grupo www-data.